# Semidirect Product $(A_{5} \times A_{5}) \rtimes Z_{2}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Consider the group $G=(A_{5} \times A_{5}) \rtimes Z_{2}$, where $A_{5} \times A_{5}$ is the normal subgroup of $G$. $Z_{2}$ acts by swapping the two copies of $A_{5}$.

I checked with gap that $A_{5} \times A_{5}$ is the unique minimal normal subgroup of $G$. Is it possible to prove that without calculation?

$A_{5}$ is the alternating group of degree $5$ and $Z_{2}$ is the cyclic subgroup of order $2$.

Comment: You have not defined $G$ uniquely, so your question does not make sense. To define a semidirect product $G \rtimes H$ you have to specify an action of $H$ on $G$, and without doing that you have not defined the group. There are several possible actions of $Z_2$ on $A_5 \times A_5$. In some of them there is a unique normal subgroup of $G$, and in others there is not. So please specify the action.

Comment: Sorry, I was having some confusion. I just added the action which is exactly as mentioned below in the answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume $Z_2$ acts by swapping the two copies of $A_5$. Let $K = A_5 \times A_5$. Write $K_1$ and $K_2$ for the two copies of $A_5$, that are the components of the direct product.

Consider first the normal subgroups of $K$. We want to show that they are $1, K_1, K_2, K$. Since $A_5$ is simple, $1 < K_1 < K$ is a [chief series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chief_series) of $G$, a (nontrivial, proper) normal subgroup $M$ of $K$ must be isomorphic to $A_5$. If $M \ne K_1$, then $M$ and $K_1$ intersect trivially (because they are both simple and normal, and thus minimal normal in $K$), and thus they commute. Since $C_K(K_1) = K_2$, we have $M = K_2$.

Now since $Z_2$ swaps $K_1$ and $K_2$, the only nontrivial normal subgroup of $G$ contained in $K$ must be $K$ itself, so $K$ is minimal normal.

Now $1 < K < G$ is a chief series of $G$, so a minimal normal $N$ subgroup of $G$ is

1. either isomorphic to $K$, or
2. of order 2,

If $N \ne K$, the first case cannot occur, since two distinct minimal normal subgroup have trivial intersection.

If $N$ has order 2, then $G \cong K \times N$, which is not the case.

Comment: You're welcome!